# PySpark - Add incrementing integer rank value based on descending order from another column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I got a pyspark dataframe that looks like:

| id | score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.5 |
| 1 | 2.5 |
| 2 | 4.45 |
| 3 | 8.5 |
| 3 | 3.25 |
| 3 | 5.55 |

And I want to create a new column `rank` based on the value of the `score` column in incrementing order meaning the highest value will have the rank `0` and restarting the count by the `id` column.

Something like this:

| id | value | rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.5 | 0 |
| 1 | 0.5 | 1 |
| 2 | 4.45 | 0 |
| 3 | 8.5 | 0 |
| 3 | 5.55 | 1 |
| 3 | 3.25 | 2 |

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.dense_rank`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.dense_rank.html) which  returns the rank of rows within a window partition.

Note that for this to work exactly we have to add an `orderBy` as `dense_rank()` requires window to be ordered. Finally let's subtract -1 on the outcome (as the default starts from 1)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df =  df.withColumn(
  "rank", dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(desc("score"))) - 1)
```

```
>>> df.show()

+---+-----+----+
| id|score|rank|
+---+-----+----+
|  1|  2.5|   0|
|  1|  0.5|   1|
|  2| 4.45|   0|
|  3|  8.5|   0|
|  3| 5.55|   1|
|  3| 3.25|   2|
+---+-----+----+
```

---

`SQL` syntax:

```
SELECT dense_rank()(value_expr) OVER (PARTITION BY window_partition ORDER BY window_ordering) from table
```